# Change image default white background

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, css-selectors

I have a div with a anchor tag. Inside the anchor tag I want to have an image. Basically, the image come with a white background. I'm trying to change this background to div's color (grey). The photo is a square and the part left from image has a white background. Is there any possibility to change this??

```
<div class="container">
            <a target="_blank" href="">
                <input class="image" type="image" alt="" src="photo.png">
            </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried saving the image with a transparent background?

Comment: [you could manipulate the image with `filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter), although you're probably better off changing your images color manually before using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the white background is part of the image, it means the image file contains white pixels as background, you won't be able to change it with code (in a simple way).
I suggest you edit the picture using https://www.photopea.com/ or any other image editing software (Photoshop, Gimp, ...) to delete those white pixels, then save the picture as PNG to keep its transparency aspect.

Answer (score -1):

Ya if the image only contains that white background then it cant be changed using javascript, so you need to use any of the online softwares to edit your picture.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).